# How to put exception handled code in a Delphi exception handler?

Tags: delphi, exception

I am writing an error handler that tried to fix or mitigate the error.  If the mitigation code errors I want to ignore the mitigation error and raise the original error.  This is the error handler I have written.

```
try
  // <Normal code>
  raise Exception.Create('Original error');
except
  on E: Exception do
  try
    // <Attempt to mitigate the error>  // If successful will continue without an exception
    raise Exception.Create('Mitigation error'); 
  except
    raise E;  // Mitigation failed, raise original error
  end;
end;
```

The above does not work.  When the mitigation exception triggers the application descends into a chaos of invalid pointers.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: What is the purpose of nested `try`..`except`? The issue is that you use `raise E` to re-raise the original exception. This is what you should do instead: `on E: Exception do if not TryMitigate(E) then raise;`.

Comment: @PeterWolf The point is, I guess, that the mitigation can raise an exception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
try
  // <Normal code>
  raise Exception.Create('Original error');
except
  on E: Exception do
  try
    // <Attempt to mitigate the error>  // If successful will continue without an exception
    raise Exception.Create('Mitigation error'); 
  except
    raise E;  // Mitigation failed, raise original error
  end;
end;
```

Once you handle an exception, it will be destroyed at the end of the `except` block which handles it. However, you do `raise E` which propagates the exception beyond that block, and beyond the end of its life.

If you wish to [re-raise an exception, and thus prolong its life beyond the block which handles it](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Exceptions_(Delphi)#Re-raising_Exceptions), then you need to use different syntax, unadorned `raise`. However, you cannot do that inside the nested `except` block since that would refer to the mitigation error. Instead you need to write `raise` in the outer `except` block:

```
procedure Foo;
var
  MitigationSucceeded: Boolean;
begin
  try
    // <Normal code>
    raise Exception.Create('Original error');
  except
    on E: Exception do
    begin
      try
        MitigationSucceeded := True;
        // <Attempt to mitigate the error>  // If successful will continue without an exception
        raise Exception.Create('Mitigation error');
      except
        // using raise here would refer to mitigation error ...
        MitigationSucceeded := False;
      end;

      if not MitigationSucceeded then
        // ... but used here it is the original error
        raise;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Perfect.  Thank-you David.